# Any Way to do ElasticSearch Range queries on multiple fields with OR operation?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

Problem: Get documents which were created (field: created_at) OR updated (field: updated_at) after a particular datetime.

Solution So Far: Using

```
boolQueryBuilder.must(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("after.created_at").gte(timeInMillis * 1000));
            boolQueryBuilder.must(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("after.updated_at").gte(timeInMillis * 1000));
```

I get the following Query:

```
"query":  {
  "bool" : {
    "must" : [
      {
        "wrapper" : {
          "query" : "eyJib29sIjp7Im11c3Rfbm90IjpbeyJtYXRjaCI6eyJhZnRlci50aXRsZSI6eyJxdWVyeSI6IldOQkEiLCJvcGVyYXRvciI6ImFuZCJ9fX0seyJtYXRjaCI6eyJmaWVsZC5kZXNjcmlwdGlvbiI6eyJxdWVyeSI6IldOQkEiLCJvcGVyYXRvciI6ImFuZCJ9fX1dLCJzaG91bGQiOlt7Im1hdGNoIjp7ImFmdGVyLnRpdGxlIjoiZmluYWxzIn19LHsibWF0Y2giOnsiZmllbGQuZGVzY3JpcHRpb24iOiJmaW5hbHMifX1dfX0="
        }
      },
      {
        "range" : {
          "after.created_at" : {
            "from" : 1603332110000000,
            "to" : null,
            "include_lower" : true,
            "include_upper" : true,
            "boost" : 1.0
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "range" : {
          "after.updated_at" : {
            "from" : 1603332110000000,
            "to" : null,
            "include_lower" : true,
            "include_upper" : true,
            "boost" : 1.0
          }
        }
      }
    ]
    "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
    "boost" : 1.0
  }
}
}
```

(Ignore the wrapped query in the beginning).

**Problem is it's getting me hits where documents were created AND updated after 1603332110000000.
How can I build the query so that I can get document created OR updated after  1603332110000000 ?** Or is there no way to do it in a single query and I will have to execute two queries for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**must is the same as logical AND operator and should is the same as logical OR operator**

You need to use `should` clause

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "wrapper": {
            "query": "eyJib29sIjp7Im11c3Rfbm90IjpbeyJtYXRjaCI6eyJhZnRlci50aXRsZSI6eyJxdWVyeSI6IldOQkEiLCJvcGVyYXRvciI6ImFuZCJ9fX0seyJtYXRjaCI6eyJmaWVsZC5kZXNjcmlwdGlvbiI6eyJxdWVyeSI6IldOQkEiLCJvcGVyYXRvciI6ImFuZCJ9fX1dLCJzaG91bGQiOlt7Im1hdGNoIjp7ImFmdGVyLnRpdGxlIjoiZmluYWxzIn19LHsibWF0Y2giOnsiZmllbGQuZGVzY3JpcHRpb24iOiJmaW5hbHMifX1dfX0="
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [
        {
          "range": {
            "after.created_at": {
              "from": 1603332110000000,
              "to": null,
              "include_lower": true,
              "include_upper": true,
              "boost": 1.0
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "after.updated_at": {
              "from": 1603332110000000,
              "to": null,
              "include_lower": true,
              "include_upper": true,
              "boost": 1.0
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "adjust_pure_negative": true,
      "boost": 1.0
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This makes sense. However doing this is giving me all documents with null values as both of the fields I'm working with can be null. `"updated_by" : null,
            "created_at" : null,`

Comment: Also tried to use existsQuery with the two fields but I'm getting zero hits with that.
`boolQueryBuilder.must(QueryBuilders.existsQuery("after.created_at"))`

Answer (score 0):

Use should with minimumNumberShouldMatch:

```
BoolQueryBuilder orQuery = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
orQuery.should(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("after.created_at").gte(timeInMillis * 1000));
orQuery.should(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("after.updated_at").gte(timeInMillis * 1000));
orQuery.minimumNumberShouldMatch(1);
```

Comment: Hmm... this should, in theory, work but it isn't working. I'm getting zero hits.